# Vue - switch one image in v-for array of images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this array I'm using `v-for` to create 3 columns of info. In each column is an image. When I mouse over 1 column/image I want to change JUST that image, none of the others. How can I accomplish this with Vue?

My Vue code looks like this:

```
<v-row
  align="center"
  justify="center"
>
  <v-col cols="4"
    v-for='(billingPlan, index) in billingPlans.basicPlans' 
    :key='billingPlan.id'
  >
    <v-img 
      :src="whichRose"
      @mouseenter="switchRose(index)"
    >
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I'm thinking I can somehow target the image by its index, but I'm not having any luck.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Where is `whichRose` coming from? If that is a computed property, you should be able to dynamically change what that property evaluates to.

Comment: `whichRose` is a data element, but `switchRose` is a computed property that I'm trying to use to update `whichRose` if that makes sense

Comment: Your configuration will never work then.  A single `whichRose` data element will be the same for all columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work?

```
<v-row
  align="center"
  justify="center"
>
  <v-col cols="4"
    v-for='(billingPlan, index) in billingPlans.basicPlans' 
    :key='billingPlan.id'
  >
    <v-img 
      :src="billingPlan.hovered ? billingPlan.image2 : billingPlan.image1"
      @mouseenter="billingPlan.hovered = true"
    >
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Would also need to add functionality if you want the image to change when you hover away.

Edit: To ensure proper reactivity, each `billingPlan` should have the property `hover` initiated to 0 before the component is created so that the reactive `src` attribute knows to rerender when `hover` changes.

Comment: nothing but awesome! great idea, worked like a champ! thanks so much